# UPDATE query syntax error in vb.net using mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image]here my query if anyone can spot error

```
    str = "update student set course='" & ComboBox1.Text & "',name='" & 
TextBox2.Text & "',f_name='" & TextBox3.Text & "',address='" & TextBox4.Text 
& "' ,tel_no='" & TextBox5.Text & "',qualification='" & TextBox6.Text & 
"',remarks='" & TextBox7.Text & "',school/college='" & TextBox8.Text & 
"',fee='" & TextBox10.Text & "' where reg_no=" & TextBox9.Text & " "
```

Comment: where am i suppose to add a from clause? i have never used from clause with update

Comment: where is the error message

Comment: and is this a name of a column? school/college

Comment: yup its the name of column.. my insert query is all good with this. i have uploaded image of error message

Comment: hey! problem resolved thank  u : )

Comment: mark my answer as correct please

Comment: This code is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. You should look up how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: SQL parameters, SQL parameters, SQL parameters. I've repeated because quite often a comment stating SQL parameters, is overlooked. Joel's mentioned it, I've mentioned it and _it_ is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to build this query:

```vb
str = "update student " &
        " set course= @course, name= @name, f_name= @fname, address= @address," & 
        " tel_no= @tel, qualification = @qualification, remarks= @remarks," & 
        " `school/college`=@school, fee= @fee" &
      " where reg_no= @regno"

Using cn  As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, cn)

    'Use actual column types/lengths from your DB here
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@course", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = TextBox2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", MySqlDbtype.VarChar, 25).Value = TextBox3.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 120).Value = TextBox4.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tel", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = TextBox5.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@qualification", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = TextBox6.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@remarks", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = TextBox7.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@school", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = TextBox8.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fee", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 6, 2).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox10.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@regno", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Integer.Parse(TextBox9.Text)

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This does a number of things for you:

1. It prevents sql injection attacks
2. It allows you to accept data that includes things like single quotes (`'`). The code you have will fail if someone puts in a single quote.
3. It handles things like date formatting for the sql automatically.
4. It's faster, because the database server can cache the execution plan after it compiles the query, and use statistics over time to get better execution plans.
5. It closes the db connection more reliably. The current code leaves the database connection hanging open if an exception is thrown.